# Is the list of cities that can be set for current city or hometown available?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, location

It doesn't look like the input that FB uses for current city and hometown is available as a widget or dialog for developers to use. I'd like to create an autocomplete input field that uses the same names for cities and the corresponding ID's. There's the lists of the cities that FB publishes for post and ad targeting but that is incomplete and appears to be using a different ID space; I'd like the same cities and IDs that are available to users when they edit their current city on their profile.  Using jquery to do the autocomplete part is doable but I just can't find an API or data source available to populate it.

Does anybody know how to access that data from the graph API, fql or any other Facebook sanctioned means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havn't seen a graph api or fql method for this.  The best I have seen from Facebook is this list: https://www.facebook.com/ads/api/autocomplete_data.php which you would want to parse and cache the json since its a pretty big download.   If you needed more details about the location, you could call the graph api by the id provided in that file.

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely more complete than the downloadable CSV files that Facebook publishes. However the ID's don't appear to be graph api ID's - look for the entry for 'San Francisco' ... the ID 2421836 isn't the one I'd expect, the graph api ID for it 114952118516947 (e.g. https://graph.facebook.com/114952118516947 or 'SELECT name,description,geometry,latitude,longitude,checkin_count,display_subtext FROM place WHERE page_id=114952118516947' both return the 'San Francisco' city page). Anybody know how the ads API ID's can be converted to graph API IDs?

Comment: This is not working any more. Any other option for it?